# How to highlight only the last edited row?

Tags: excel, vba, highlight

I have a table of customer data in Excel that can be added/edited using a VBA userform. Therefore I would like to highlight the row that has just been added/edited. This is my first time using VBA so I searched and found code from [here](https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/5106-excel-highlight-modified-cells.html):

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Value <> "" Then
        Target.Interior.ColorIndex = 6
    End If
End Sub
```

which works perfectly fine but the highlights for the previous edits/add-ons are still there. I just want the last one to be highlighted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a variable. Store the range in that when you are changing the color. Next time remove the color from that range.

Is this what you are trying?

```
Dim prevRng As Range

Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim aCell As Range

    If Not prevRng Is Nothing Then prevRng.Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone
    Set prevRng = Target

    For Each aCell In Target
        If aCell.Value <> "" Then aCell.Interior.ColorIndex = 6
    Next aCell
End Sub
```

This will handle multiple cells as @Pᴇʜ mentioned in the comment.

Comment: You would need  a loop for `Target` to loop through its cells. It could be a range instead of a single cell and then `Target.Value <> ""` fails.

Comment: true that... Will incorporate that... one moment

Comment: May I ask why you added the `If` statement? I mean the loop would run even on `Target` beeing one cell. Is this this such a difference in performance? Or did I miss something?

Comment: Yep, that was exactly what I was thinking about :) I mean the code not the nap

Comment: Wouldn't this disregards the range its current interior color?

Comment: @JvdV: Yes it will.

Comment: @SiddharthRout Actually I found another issue `Workbook_SheetChange` is handling **all** the sheets but there is only **one range variable** `prevRng`. So if the sheet is changed in between it will fail I think. So we woud need eg a dictionary to collect all the `prevRng` for the different sheets (and hope that the sheets don't get renamed in between or use their codename and hope there are no code generated sheets :)

Comment: @Pᴇʜ: That is a very good point. I usually think of all this but for the first time I have put a shabby answer. My apologies...

Comment: @SiddharthRout Actually this is a way more complicated than it looked at first to me too. I would have failed on this point at first too :) • Another point would be that we would need to clear the highlighting for **all** sheets on `Workbook_BeforeSave` and re-set it on `Workbook_AfterSave` (so we can continue working on a in-between-save) otherwise we will save the highlighting and and come up with pre-highlighted cells on a re-open of the workbook that will never disappear.

Comment: @SiddharthRout, would there be a way to prevent this? I'm very curious :)

Comment: @JvdV Yes, additionally to `prevRng` which stores *where* the range was that was highlighted last you would need an array to store the `ColorIndex` for each cell in `prevRng` which you could restore then. (But if one cell gets changed twice in a row here we need to be careful so it dosn't remember the highlight color in the second change.)

Comment: I am at the office so cant dedicate any time to this at the moment. Will relook at this post later tonight

Comment: Ok I have a solution in mind but I think we are being over ambitious :D User wants to handle only specific edits.. `I have a table of customer data in Excel that can be added/edited using a VBA userform.`

Comment: Before you put too much effort in this, would you consider my answer to tackle all issues at hand? And if not, please leave some constructive criticism as I am no pro and eager to learn more.

Comment: @SiddharthRout If it is just one specific table/worksheet that would need to be handled then you could just switch the `Workbook_SheetChange` to the specific `Worksheet_Change` event and your solution would fit (besides the saving effect I described). This would reduce the problem to a much simpler one.

Answer (score 1):

Here is some code that could work for you:

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)

'Removing old conditional formatting if it exists already
Conditions = ActiveSheet.Cells.FormatConditions.Count
For i = 1 to Conditions
    If ActiveSheet.Cells.FormatConditions(i).Type = 2 Then
        If ActiveSheet.Cells.FormatConditions(i).Formula1 = "=1" Then ActiveSheet.Cells.FormatConditions(i).Delete
    End If
Next i

'Adding new conditional formatting rule to the edited range
Target.EntireRow.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:="=1"
Target.EntireRow.FormatConditions(1).Interior.ColorIndex = 6

End Sub
```

Currently it will highlight all the last edited rows in all sheets. Not sure if this is what you wanted.

- It will keep colored cells in your sheet intact when a new range has been changed.
- It will keep other conditional formatting rules intact.
- It highlights the last edited range, even if the range has been cleared!

Comment: Either run the loop backwards (`For i = Conditions To 1 Step -1`), or include an `Exit For` in the `If` statement - otherwise, you will can get an error when the `"=1"` condition is not the last one.

Comment: @Chronocidal, thank you for the headsup. I have updated the code with another if-statement because the backward iteration nor the `Exit For` strategy worked and created another error. Any theory why a `And` statement wouldn't work either?